# AWS COGNITO: Stop receiving OTP for login

Tags: amazon-cognito, awscognitotoken

I am using

```
USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
```

for authFlow. Currently Im receiving OTP for login. How can I bypass OTP

Want to stop receiving OTP for login, instead get OTP during signup

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the MFA for Cognito.

One of the options is to do so via CLI
`aws cognito-idp set-user-pool-mfa-config --mfa-configuration OFF --user-pool-id <your_user_pool_id>`

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cognito-idp/set-user-pool-mfa-config.html

Comment: Is there a way to enable MFA during signup

Comment: You should be able to configure that in Cognito new console experience.  At step 3 "Configure sign-up experience" you can check the box for "Cognito-assisted verification and confirmation" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html

Comment: Somehow Im not getting OTP for phone number verification. Instead I get a temporary password. Is that expected?